# Is there a version of Friedrich's lemma for Bochner spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $u\in H^{1}([0,T], H^{1}_{0})$ that satisfies $u_{tt}+L u=f\in L^{2}(0,T; L^{2})$.

where $L$ is a uniformly elliptic operator in divergence form given by

$$L=(a^{ij}(t,x)u_{x^{i}})_{x^{j}}$$

where $a^{ij}(t,x)\in C^{1}([0,T],L^{\infty})$

Let consider a mollified sequence of function given by  $$\{u^{\epsilon}(t,x)=\eta^{\epsilon}(t)*(\xi u(t,x))\}$$ where $\{\eta^{\epsilon}(t)\}_{\epsilon}$ is a strict delta net and $\xi$ is a smooth cut-off function vanishing outside the interval $(0,T]$ and equal to one in some subinterval $I\subset (0,T)$

Is it true that $u_{tt}^{\epsilon}+Lu^{\epsilon}\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}, L^{2}(\Sigma))$ and that when $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ we have that$u_{tt}^{\epsilon}+Lu^{\epsilon}\rightarrow u_{tt}+Lu$ in  $L^{2}$?

I am thinking about using [Theorem 1.5.7](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=uaMCAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA46&lpg=PA46&dq=commutator+mollifiers&source=bl&ots=BFwEji8s9G&sig=ilec1frXy_NjZo_iXhKyelSLscE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwics43T6LHLAhUEPBoKHZIYBAwQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=commutator%20mollifiers&f=false) in *Linear and Quasi-linear Evolution Equations in Hilbert Spaces* by Pascal Cherrier and Albert Milani, but I am not sure if the result hold for Bochner spaces. The theorem is as follows:

> [image: thm]